# Running Emma with Eclipse on Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, emma

I'm trying to use Emma coverage tool with Eclipse, but i'm a little confused.

So I added emma.jar and emma_ant.jar into /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-common/jre/lib/ext/emma/ directory and created a Java Project under Eclipse using JRE: java-6-openjdk

I copied a build.xml example file into my project and edited the emma.dir property to /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-common/jre/lib/ext/emma/

Then, when I create a .jar file, and try to run it with Emma:

> java emmarun -jar HelloWorld.jar

I get this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: emmarun
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: emmarun at 
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
>   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
>   Could not find the main class: emmarun. Program will exit.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it the hard way. Install the [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) plugin and you just have to select the correct launch configuration to get test coverage.

Update: I just realized that EclEmma uses [JaCoCo](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco) internally, and no longer Emma. Still, it's a great tool, I'd go with it nevertheless.

But to solve your problem: I don't think you can have subfolders in lib/ext. Move the jar directly inside lib/ext and it should work.

Comment: I try to move the jar directly inside lib/ext but I still get the same error.

Comment: Find the answer! The right command is java -cp /path/to/emma.jar emmarun [OPTION] -jar yourown.jar

Answer (score 0):

Just install ecl-emma through the eclipse install center!

Go on Help -> Install Software, insert there the ecl-emma page:

```
http://update.eclemma.org/
```

And go through the the installation assistant.